# Remove multiple strings using replace

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to remove "FC", "AFC" or "London" if a string includes those strings. I have tried:

```
  $scope.teamName = function(url) {
            return url.replace('AFC'|'London'|'FC', '');
        };
```

String could be for example "Arsenal London FC".

Doesn't work though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
return url.replace(/AFC|London|FC/ig, "");
```

"i" = Case Insensitive

"g" = Global match (find all matches rather stopping after the first match)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `/AFC|London|FC/g` to get all matches:

```js
var str = "Arsenal London FC";
alert(str.replace(/AFC|London|FC/g, ''));
```

Comment: What if football clup's name contains FC like OFFCAST ?

Comment: It will fail just like the regular replace. :) OP said: `if a string includes those strings`, but that's why I left it case sensitive.